# How to scroll to the top of a table view in iOS 15

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios15

How do you scroll to the very top of a table view in iOS 15?

These ways don't seem to work.

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];

[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

This way worked great in prior versions, but iOS 15 puts new padding above each table header section, and this no longer scrolls to the exact top in iOS 15.

It scrolls to the first table header section, but below it's padding, so about 20 pixels off from the very top.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Comment: Are you using a `UITableViewController` or a `UITableView` as a subview? Storyboard / IB or via code? In a navigation controller?

Comment: It's a custom view controller with a table view. `UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't think I'm experiencing what you are. Is the "padding" not showing, but it should? Or, is the "padding" showing but you don't want it to?

Comment: Or... do you want to remove the "padding" on all the section headers?

Comment: I want it to scroll all the way to the top. Right now, it scrolls 20 pixels below the top.

Comment: Is this your goal? https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6yNE.png (same view controller class, just iOS 15.2 on left, iOS 13.3 on right)